# Android Studio update to 3.0.1 went wrong

Tags: android, android-studio

I just updated my Android Studio to 3.0.1 and it's plug ins. Unfortunately the adb.exe  file was recognized from Avast as virus and was locked down and now can't be restored. Any solution to this particular problem.

Trials: 
I tried to uninstall and install the Android SDK Platform-Tools from SDK Manager
Uninstall and install  Android Studio non of this helped.

Comment: First [Google hit](https://www.google.com/search?q=avast+restore+from+quarantine) is https://blog.avast.com/2013/11/03/how-do-i-access-the-avast-virus-chest/.

Comment: Yeah that is what i did but Avast said that can't be restored, is there any other way that i can add that file manually.